# Linq2Db not all stored procedures scaffolding

Tags: stored-procedures, scaffolding, linq2db

I've tried to scaffold an existing database using cli

```
dotnet linq2db scaffold -p Firebird -c "Server=;Database=;User Id=;Password=" --objects table,stored-procedure,aggregate-function  --overwrite true
```

In result some stored procedures scaffold, but some do not. As I understand no scaffolding procedures which have out parameters.

Comment: Create discussion in [github](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/discussions). Responsible for scaffolding person do not visit SO.